# Nocedal & Wright — proof of theorem 3.7

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, numerical-optimization

On page 47 of Nocedal & Wright's [Numerical Optimization](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-40065-5), the authors provide a proof for Theorem 3.7 and there is
one idea that I didn't understand. The authors prove the following inequality:

$$\|x_k+p_k-x^*\| \le \|x_k+p_k^N-x^*\| + \|p_k-p_k^N\| = 
O(\|x_k - x^*\|^2) + o(\|p_k\|)$$

and say that a simple manipulation of the above inequality reveals that

$$\|p_k\|=O(\|x_k-x^*\|).$$

**Question**: What ideas and manipulation are needed to prove that $\|p_k\|=O(\|x_k-x^*\|)$ from the above inequality?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question. Any advice is helpful.

Comment: Since the link to the PDF file is broken, I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$\|p_k\| \le \|x_k -x^*\| + \|x_k + p_k -x^* \| $, and
so,
$\|p_k\| \le \|x_k -x^*\| + O(\|x_k-x^*\|^2) + o(\|p_k\|)$.

Choose $K$ large enough so that $o(\|p_k\|) \le {1 \over 2} \|p_k\|$, then
for $k \ge K$ you have
${1 \over 2} \|p_k\| \le \|x_k -x^*\| + O(\|x_k-x^*\|^2)$, from which the result follows.

Comment: I am not a fan of o/O calculations for proofs of this sort as it often 'loses' constants which can provide intuition.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! ${}{}$

Comment: @jjjjjj: I don't follow your question?

Comment: Oops, nvm, I think I was wrong, thanks!